# Mudblazor-MudDataGrid cell click event

Tags: blazor, .net-7.0, mudblazor

i m building a blazor server app, using .NET Core 7 and i m using the **Mudblazor** UI component library. I m having trouble finding a way to intercept the **cell click event**, of a row. My main goal is to be able to get the row-cell that was clicked. I am able to catch the Row click event, but this is not what i m after. I need the actual cell that the user clicked, if this is provided by the component.

I m attaching the existing blazor code:

```
<MudDataGrid T="Element" MultiSelection="true" Items="@Elements" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" QuickFilter="@_quickFilter"
                         Hideable="true" RowClick="@RowClicked" SelectedItemsChanged="@SelectedItemsChanged">
                <ToolBarContent>
                    <MudSpacer />
                    <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Table Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                                  AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
                    <MudButton Style="background-color:coral;color:white;margin-left: 20px;" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add">
                        @if (!isMobileDevice)
                        {
                            <span>New Item</span>
                        }
                    </MudButton>
                </ToolBarContent>
                <Columns>
                    <SelectColumn T="Element" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.SKU" Title="SKU Number" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" Title="Name" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" CellStyleFunc="@_cellStyleFunc" onclick="OnCellClick" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quentity" Title="Qty On-Hand" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Measurement" Title="UOM" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Location" Title="Location" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Type" Title="Type" Sortable="true" Filterable="true" />
                    <TemplateColumn CellClass="justify-end">
                        <CellTemplate>
                            <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" AnchorOrigin="@Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="@Origin.TopRight">
                                <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit">Edit</MudMenuItem>
                                <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.ContentCopy">Duplicate</MudMenuItem>
                                <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.MultipleStop">Transfer Qty</MudMenuItem>
                                <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Archive">Archive</MudMenuItem>
                            </MudMenu>
                        </CellTemplate>
                    </TemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerContent>
                    <MudDataGridPager T="Element" />
                </PagerContent>
            </MudDataGrid>
```

I have tried adding an OnClick event, at the PropertyColumn tag, but the event is not being fired. I have also searched the documentation, but there does not seem to contain information for this functionality. I have also searched on the internet, but this has not bare fruit either!

Alternatively, i would like to be able to create a clickable cell, and respond to the clicked event, by also receiving the row data.

Any help would be really appreciated, since the grid works really well, out of the box.

Comment: I don't think MudBlazor implements UI events on `PropertyColumn`.   You can ask the MudBlazor team a question here - https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already posted a question there, prior to utilizing stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TemplateColumn`>`CellTemplate`>display component.

Then, you can add the @onclick event on the display component. Where you can access the items defined in `MudDataGrid` by using `context.Item`

```
<MudDataGrid T="MyObject" Items="@_myObjectsCollection" RowClick="@RowClicked">
    <TemplateColumn Title="Name">
        <CellTemplate>
            <MudText @onclick="@(()=>RowCellClicked(context.Item.Name))">@context.Item.Name</MudText>
        </CellTemplate>
    </TemplateColumn>
</MudDataGrid>

@code
{
    List<MyObject> _myObjectsCollection;

    void RowCellClicked(string name)
    {
        // cell clicked logic
    }
}
```

[mudblazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYwHEolYUzPqezjl)

Comment: Hi @RBee and thank you for responding. However i m already doing this. I want to create a clickable cell, within the row, and respond to that, instead of the entire row click!

Comment: @SotirisZegiannis Ahh I see, you can use `TemplateColumn` > `CellTemplate` > and add another component in there to use the @onclick for the specific row-cell. There you can access the row item using the `context` property. See if this helps [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYwHEolYUzPqezjl) .

Comment: i ll give this a try. Mudblazor is a good ui blazor component library, but the documentation is not good and doesnt explain that much,besides the examples!

Answer (score 1):

They have since added RowClick

```
<MudDataGrid RowClick="(e) => DoThing(e.Item)"/>
```